# Uploading a file from React to S3 Gives CORS errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

Not sure what's wrong with my CORS settings

## No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

[image: Error]

## S3 Bucket CORS settings

[image: S3 Bucket CORS Setting]

Answer (score 0):

That will not be enough. You also need to add CORS setting to the header as well.
For example, this worked for me with Axios:

```
let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
}, 
  crossDomain: true

};
```

If you use API Gateway, you must set CORS there as well. 
There is also an option to add https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ as a prefix to your URL, but I am not sure is it good idea or not.